# Any problems with putting DAOs and Gateways in Application.cfc?

Tags: coldfusion, scope, dao, gateway, application.cfc

Is it ok to put DAOs and Gateways that will be called many times but only need to be instantiated once in the Application scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Another option is to use an IOC framework such as ColdSpring or some other bean factory. The bean factory can then be stored in the application scope and instantiated onApplicationStart() (effectively achieving the same thing but possibly with more control).

Comment: Thanks Dom, I'll definitely be using a framework with my next CF project, but in the mean time I'll put them the Application scope.

Answer (score 3):

That's the perfect place to put them ;-).

Add them into onApplicationStart() as application.myDAO = xxxx  & application.myGateway = xxxx and you're good to go!

Comment: Thanks for your response and the implementation example, I'm good to go now.